# How to count the number of individual users in a table per day?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a log table that lists various actions of a system, including user logins. I want to find out how many unique users logged in during each day.

I tried this here:

```
SELECT date, count(username) 
FROM universal_log 
WHERE (plugin,action) 
IN (('system','login')) 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date
```

which however gives me the amount of people who logged in, counting also all multiple logins by each user. I figured this is because I did not group by username. However if I do this here:

```
SELECT date, count(username) 
FROM universal_log 
WHERE (plugin,action) 
IN (('system','login')) 
GROUP BY date, username
ORDER BY date
```

I get a table with several entries per date instead of one, with the count how often each user logged in during that day.

How can I get a count +1 for each user when he logged in per day, no matter how often he logged in on that day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a [`COUNT(DISTINCT username)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) should solve the duplications for you when applied to your first query.  You were correct to `GROUP BY date` only, but just need to deduplicate the `username` values.

```
SELECT
  date,
  count(DISTINCT username) 
FROM universal_log 
WHERE (plugin,action) 
  IN (('system','login')) 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date
```

When you added `username` to the `GROUP BY` in your second attempt, that had the effect of applying the `COUNT()` per `date`, per `username`, which is semantically different from what you want.  For each column added to the `GROUP BY`, your aggregate will end up  either producing *more* rows (applied over a wider data set) or in some cases the same rows (if the values were all distinct to begin with).